# How to count # lates per student name?

Tags: google-sheets, formula

[sample attendance (google) sheet](https://docs.google.com/a/ahschools.com/spreadsheets/d/1jQwpsH84EsNoMfDoH0rKvXnPuhCvULLUQioqZwFQ4Nk/edit#gid=0)

I want count the number of total lates per student name on this sample sheet, e.g, how many lates Mary Love has (actual sheet has over 30,000 rows, 10 columns).  If possible, this count needs to change as students have additional lates. I'd really appreciate any help someone might be able to provide. I thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous post, a QUERY() function also seems a good option as it can output a 2D-array, containing the names and the counts in one formula (no need to drag down). As an example, try:

```
=query(A:G, "select A, count(B) where B ='Late' group by A ", 1)
```

If you want to limit the result tho those who had more then 3 late's, you can do:

```
=query(query(A:G, "select A, count(B) where B ='Late' group by A ", 1), "where Col2 > 3")
```

Also further filtering with date can be done very easily. However I think that may require some 'cleaning up' of the current data: I noticed a lot of different date formats in col D... :-)

Comment: JPV, Kevin, you have been so very helpful!!! I want to apply your formulas now to the 'real' spreadsheet. I'll get back to you very soon (sorry for my delaly this evening). Again, thank you very much, both of you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the COUNTIFS function to get what you are looking for. This formula will count all matches for multiple criteria ranges and criteria (e.g. student name & late).

This is the syntax for the formula:

COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2]…)

If you put Mary Love in cell I2, you could then put this in J2.

```
=countifs(B:B,"=late", A:A,I2)
```

Then as more rows are added it will automatically update the "lates". I would also suggest using named ranges, then you could replace B:B and A:A with the named range.

I would suggest using the =query function as documented below. If that doesn't meet your needs you could modify the above:

```
=if (countifs(B:B,"=Late", A:A,I2, D:D, ">="&N2) >= 3, "True", "False")
```

This will put "True" in the column if there are 3 or more lates, false if not. This will require you put the date you want to check against in column N2. Change N2 above if you want to use a different column.

Comment: This is great, Kevin! Your answer, not surprisingly, triggered another question: how might I combine this formula with another that filters the date column so that I could do the following, for example: all students with 3 or more lates after March 16, 2015? I'm very sorry to presume further on your expertise and your kindness, but I'd truly appreciate your help with this last question. I thank you very much! Brian.

Comment: @Brian - did you see JPV's answer below? If you don't want to use that let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Kevin, if you wouldn't mind, what would you suggest as an alternative? Thank you.

Comment: =if (countifs(B:B,"=Late", A:A,I2, D:D, ">3/15/2014") >= 3, "True", "False") Kevin, thank you for this formula, too. I'm having a problem getting a correct number, however. I imagine it's a date problem. Two questions: I thought the dates were already in a separate column...no? I don't understand "hard coding." (sorry for my lack of understanding). Anyway, almost there. Thanks, Kevin! Brian.

Comment: @Brian - I think the date didn't work because google doesn't allow you to hard code it for a countif formula. I revised the answer above to correct this. Hard coding when you type something manually (e.g. "3/15/2015") instead of using a variable (putting "3/15/2015" in column N2 and using that in the formula). This way next month you could just update N2 to "4/15/2015" and everything would automatically update. Please accept the answer if you like it now :)

Comment: I get it now, and I do like it, Kevin. It's working very well, BTW! I think the problem with the 'real' sheet column of dates is that one or two of our teachers inadvertenly selected the wrong month (e.g., September 15, 2015 instead of 2014. I'm not sure how that could happen, but I'll find out tomorrow if my hunch is correct. Anyway, to you and all who helped me so kindly, I can only thank you by hoping to help others in some small way. My best!

Answer (score 0):

For counting each of several students and to allow greater versatility I suggest a pivot table with `Student Name` for **Rows**, `Late` for **Values** with Summarise by: COUNTA and `Late` for **Filter** with Show: Late.